# Writting and Update Query from one Data Extension to another Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

There is a Field called `Program_Status` in Data Extension (DE) `[Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822]` and I would like to update this field based on DE `Program_Interest_G` that has the field named `[Status]`

I tried the following TWO syntax:

```
Select 
Program_Interest_G.Status as [Program_Status]
FROM [Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822] v
LEFT JOIN Program_Interest_G ON v.Global_Program_of_Interest_1__c = Program_Interest_G.ProgramOfInterest
```

OR

```
Select 
Status as [Program_Status]
FROM Program_Interest_G
```

With both syntax error the same comment:

> An error occurred saving the definition:
>   A problem occurred creating your query definition. Please contact Customer Service for additional information.
>   Name: Update Program 1 Status
>   External Key: Update_Program_1_Status
>   Error saving the Query field.Field 'Lead:Id' is a required for the Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query text.

The issue is the first DE is just a list of Programs and the status of each program. Only the other DE that I'm trying to update has Lead.ID's

Comment: Can you post the columns in the target de? If you don’t have a lead.id then you can use that source de for the query

Comment: Target:
Lead:Email
Lead:Id
Lead:FirstName
Lead:LastName
Global_School_Program_of_Interest_1__c
Global_Program_of_Interest_1__c
Lead:Program_Status__c
                                                                                                                                                    
========================================                                                                                                                           
Source:
SchoolProgram
ProgramOfInterest
ProgramCode
Status

Comment: Does Lead:Id have the `nullable` field ticked?

Comment: No Lead:id is not Ticket nullable

Comment: Should I chnage this to ticked?

Comment: Actually Just tried to uncheck nullable but it's unchangeable. I can add/delete new fields but not edit the Nullable in the existing fields

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new DE to and make sure all field that wont be part of the query are nullable.
- Use this Query to copy the data into the new DE

  ```
  SELECT * From

  SchoolProgram ProgramOfInterest ProgramCode Status

  Target DE: Your new DE
  ```

Your query should work now

Comment: Hi there. Thx for the suggestion. I need the DE related to the Journey Builder updated [Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822] . Therefore creating a third DE would not resolve my issue. thx much though

Comment: Replace this De with the one in contact builder and use it for your journey?

Comment: alternatively you can populate the School Program DE with a Lead:ID column Select that in the join

Comment: I got it working with the JB DE and without having to create an additional DE. thx much for your help. couldn't have done it without you:  [code]SELECT [Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822].[Lead:Id], Program_Interest_G.Status as [Program_Status]
FROM [Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822]
LEFT JOIN Program_Interest_G ON [Recruiter High school Visits V2 - 2018-06-25T124653822].Global_Program_of_Interest_1__c= Program_Interest_G.ProgramOfInterest [/code]